# Skycons in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a *mandatory* weather app in react, and im struggling with some icons. I'm using [Skycons](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/), but I can't get them to show up in my application. I can see in the dev tool that the icon and the path is correct, but its just plain blank where it's supposed to be.

HTML is:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="skycons.js"></script>

  <script>
    var icons = new Skycons(),
        list  = [
          "clear-day", "clear-night", "partly-cloudy-day",
          "partly-cloudy-night", "cloudy", "rain", "sleet", "snow", "wind",
          "fog"
        ],
        i;

    for(i = list.length; i--; )
      icons.set(list[i], list[i]);

    icons.play();
  </script>
</body>
```

and in my React app I call the icon like this

```
<div className="col-md-3"><canvas id={day.icon} width="64" height="64">
```

I get no console errors, so im having a hard time to debug

Comment: You never add them to the canvas?

Comment: The canvas id {day.icon} will return something like clear-day, so what to you mean that I dont add them?

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest you need `icons.add("id", ICON);`

Comment: Well. I moved the icons from the demo folder inluded, to my own app where they work. But when I load the icon from the React app, they are gone

Comment: I'm wondering whether your using react-skycons for your react app - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-skycons

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the npm commands and running builds, so I thought it would be easier to get them from https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons - so no - im not using the react once

Comment: Two things that might go wrong! did you check whether skycon.js imported gets loaded and did you check `day.icon` sets correct value, check both by inspecting in the browser and checking in resources that loaded in source tab

Comment: Both are correct. If i move the canvas to the HTML it works, but when i move it to react i can still see it in the inspector, but in the browser window its blank

Comment: I had similar issue as @frisk0, I resized my browser then saw the icon.